# python pandas unstack MultiIndex directly to sparse object

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to directly take a Series object with a three- or two-level MultiIndex and unstack it directly to a sparse DataFrame or sparse Panel? i.e. without first creating a non-sparse (dense) object?

Comment: no, unfortunately unstack currently enumerates the cartesian space of all the indices; need someone to enhance this (whom has an interest in sparse)!

Comment: @Jeff do you know if there is a dev thread/issue started about this on github? I did not find one.

Comment: I don't think so. if u do create an issue pls out in an example / detail